# Lexicographic order in python

Tags: python

> 'tactic' <= 'tree'

Can i know why 'tactic' is lexicographically smaller than 'tree' / why will it return true for the code 'tactic'<='tree' ?

From my understanding , isn't it supposed to return false since the third index of both strings , where it's supposed to be ( t is > than e ) ? Hence returning a false ?

Comment: cause `'a' < 'r'`.

Comment: isn't it supposed to check all the alphabet up to index of min ( len('tactic') , min('tree')) ?

Comment: [no](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order)

Comment: Python do not necessarily check all the letters of the word. It will check sequentially same index of both words. If anyone of it is true then Python will return true and ignore rest of the letters. Here a < r which is true thats why it returned true and ignore rest of the letters.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this behavior is that the lexicographic order is computed from front to back. The first charater that is different defines the order of the items.

In your example it is evaluated this way:

- first character from each string is 't' => equal, next character
- second character is 'a' and 'r' => 'a' < 'r', this means the first string is smaller
  => 'tactic' < 'tree'